# MAP REACTJS no muestra resultados

Tags: reactjs, javascript-objeto

```
     {ViewDatos.map((data)=>{
        {data.data.map((valor)=>{
           return(
              <div key={valor._id}>
                 <li>{valor.user}</li>
              </div>
           )
        })}
     })}
```

Hola buenas no me deja mostrar los resultados de un map hago doble MAP por que tengo un arreglo de objeto dentro de otro pero a la hora de renderizarlo no puedo porfa ayuda

Comment: Saludos, por favor edita tu pregunta y pega el código en formato de texto (Incluyendo los mensajes por consola), solo utiliza imágenes cuando sea absolutamente necesario. ;)

Comment: oka muchas gracias por el comentario

Comment: En los map no hay return. Te pondría una respuesta con el código correcto, pero puesto que no puedo copiar y pegar texto de una imagen, me esperaré a que edites la pregunta. Te recomiendo leer [ask] y ver lo que es un [mcve]

Comment: ahi edite la pregunta para cualquier respuesta muchas gracias por las recomendaciones